# Auth::login having no effect

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8

In a Laravel application I'm calling Auth::login($user) in an endpoint that gets requested via AJAX. I'd expect that when I next visit a page I would be logged in but I'm not. The call definitely occurs, and there aren't any errors. Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: after logging in, you need to issue an access token which you'd then attach to ajax calls from your front end. 
Ajax calls are ususally authenticated by using access_token. 
So it doesn't matter if you logged in, if you make an ajax call to an auth protected route, without an access token, then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is better if you share some code, but I have two questions:

1.- When you logged from ajax after you reload the webpage? for refresh the cookies

2.- Make sure you use default config on config/auth.php In this you need to use

guard => web

guards => web => session

```
 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
```